# Moving Information From ListBox to Another ListBox that are bound to datatables

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two ListBoxes bound to DataTables. When I try to move information from one ListBox to another listbox using a button click with the following code:

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    ListBox1.Items.Add(ListBox2.SelectedItem);
    ListBox2.Items.Remove(ListBox2.SelectedItem);
}
```

One items is removed from ListBox2 and added to ListBox1 but if I try and click the button again with a newly selected item nothing happens.

I'd like to be able to move up to all the items from listbox 1 into listbox 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep two datatables, one for each list box. Move the items to their respective datatables and on your button click, rebind the listboxes to the datatables.